# Logging into JMC Via httpwebrequest vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, authentication, httpwebrequest

I have been working on this for about a day and i can't get JMC to log me in via httpwebrequests.
And i'm using this code but it's not working, it just brings me back to the home page:

```
 Dim postData As String = "ddl_schoolyear=2015&ddl_buildings=E&txt_username=txt_passworLogin_Button1.x=0&Login_Button1.y=0"
    Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
    Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
    Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)

    Dim postr As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http.aspx"), HttpWebRequest)
    postr.Method = "POST"
    postr.KeepAlive = True
    postr.CookieContainer = logcook

    postr.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    postr.Referer = "https://eastunioncsd.onlinejmc.com/Teacher/Login.aspx"
    postr.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.99 Safari/537.36"
    postr.ContentLength = byteData.Length

    Dim postrs As Stream = postr.GetRequestStream
    postrs.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    postrs.Close()

    Dim postre As HttpWebResponse
    postre = DirectCast(postr.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    tempCookies.Add(postre.Cookies)
    logcook = logcook

    Dim postreader As New StreamReader(postre.GetResponseStream())
    Dim thepage As String = postreader.ReadToEnd
    RichTextBox1.Text = thepage
```

Is there any solution anything i'm doing wrong? How can i populate the form data with the username and password, where it will log me in with a webrequest. If all information was right i'm suppose to be redirected to "https:/Teacher/Default.aspx".  I would think it would bring me to the dashboard but instead it just goes to the login page.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where are you expecting to be redirected? All you're doing is populating a RTB with response of a webservice POST... Edit your question and provide more info. Also see [ask]. Good luck!

Comment: This is the problem you need to elaborate on, the web request doesn't redirect you.. The cookies added from the web request are probably needed to get into Default.aspx after you've hit login.aspx but your code doesn't show that 'redirect' to the default.aspx/dashboard.aspx

Comment: Okay, so it works, it just doesn't show me redirecting, is there a way to check the redirect?

Comment: Dude you led me to a dodgy site.. I don't really want to help now.

Comment: It's an Educational site, what are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got from the link you posted in your comment:

[image]

Comment: Thats kinda impossible its an education site ran by my state, so ads are not allowed. Where did you get mobliegiftcenter.com from anyways it was never in any of my previous posts.